# Question about meaning of "hit form" some other highlighted words in following passage

Tags: word-meaning

> Maria Sharapova secured her place in the final of the Madrid Open for the second consecutive year with a comfortable 6-1, 6-4 win over Poland's Agnieszka Radwanska on Saturday.The four-time Grand Slam champion will face Romanian Simona Halep in Sunday's final as she **ground out** a hard-fought 6-7 (4/7), 6-3, 6-2 victory over **fifth seed** Petra Kvitova.Sharapova has slowly begun to **hit form** in recent weeks on her return to clay conditions after a difficult start to the year and she stormed through the opening set **for the loss of just 11 points**.

Though, based on my intuition, **ground out** is just a typo, and should be **grounded out** , and **fifth seed** has to do with five times bcoming champion in the past, I have completly drawn a blank, defining **hit form** and "for the loss".

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This *ground* is the past tense of *grind*. The seed is something they sort competitors in a tournament (the top seed or seed #1 is the one who is most likely to win the tournament). I'm not familiar with "hit from", but "return to someone's form" means they play in their good form or top form.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Ground out

> The four-time Grand Slam champion will face Romanian Simona Halep in Sunday's final as she **ground out** a hard-fought 6-7 (4/7), 6-3, 6-2 victory over **fifth seed** Petra Kvitova.

*Ground out* is not a typo, it is the past tense of ***[grind out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/grind-out)*** (= to produce something in large quantities, especially when this is boring or difficult).

This means that Simona Halep didn't win her match easily (as also suggested by *"a hard-fought"*) victory.

#### 2. The fifth seed

A ***[seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_%28sports%29)*** in sports is usually refers to those who are ranked before the tournament begins. This can be used for many purposes, such as for the arrangement of the matches (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_%28sports%29)). Seed numbers are also helpful to predict who is likely to win the tournament. Winning the ***fifth seed*** is certainly not easy. (The top seed or the #1 seed is the highest seed. In other words, the best player in the tournament.)

#### 3. Hit form

> Sharapova has slowly begun to **hit form** in recent weeks on her return to clay conditions after a difficult start to the year and she stormed through the opening set **for the loss of just 11 points**.

Someone's ***[form](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/form)*** refers to "the level of someone's ability at a particular time, especially in a sport". Ideally, an athlete would want to play in their top form, or at least in good form. Saying that Sharapova has begun to ***hit form*** means that Sharapova was able to "reach her form", or was able to play the way people would expect her to play.

#### 4. For the loss of just 11 points

*"She stormed through the opening set **for the loss of just 11 points**"* simply means that she lost only 11 points (in total) to her opponent (Agnieszka Radwanska) in the first set.

<sub>Here is a little note on how we play tennis. A typical match is to win two out of three or three out of five sets. A set consists of games. In each set, the side that wins 6 games first, win. (There is a special condition called "tie-break", which is necessary when the set is tied at 6-6.) A game consists of **points**. A player (or a team) will get one point usually when the other cannot return a good ball (to land in an appropriate part of the court). The point in a game goes from 0 (called "love") to 15, 30, 40, and then (end of a) game. Each of these points is called one point or "**a point**".</sub>